# Тема для школьной выпускной работы (веб-программирование)

Tags: веб-программирование

Привет, уже месяц ломаю голову над темой для выпускной работы в 11 классе. Знаю HTML CSS (в т.ч. HTML5 и CSS3), хорошо владею PHP (осваиваю ООП, паттерны проектирования и т.д.). Владею основами JavaScript и JQuery. Хочется связать все это в какую-нибудь интересную работу, которую можно будет выполнить за 7-8 месяцев.

Comment: @tooq, какой сложности требуется проект. Ну, или хотя бы на сколько часов работы?

Comment: Что такое выпускная работа? Я школу закончил и про выпускную работы ни слова не слышал.

Comment: Читайте новый закон об образовании.

Comment: Выпускная работа - это такая ужасная вещь, которую придумал много лет назад наш лицей. Все ученики 11 класса должны написать работу (на уровне курсовой), по одному из профильных предметов. В общем в феврале 2013 года работу нужно сдать, но для этого хотябы нужно придумать тему :)

Comment: Всем вам спасибо конечно за поддержку, но может подскажете что-нибудь? =)

Comment: @tooq, сделайте что нибудь простенькое, но аккуратно. Не знаю, чем Вы занимаетесь кроме учебы. 

Ну, допустим сайт школьных турниров по пинг-понгу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, например, написать приложение для построения блок-схем с использованием HTML5. Допустим, есть канвас и кнопки управления, соответствующие возможным элементам блок-схемы: цикл, ветвление, вызов функции, простой оператор, конец блок-схемы. Сначала есть только блок "начало" и стрелка вниз. Затем пользователь нажимает на кнопки и вводит текст, который будет внутри блока. И таким образом создает блок-схему. В интернете есть несколько похожих решений на Flash, но чаще всего это инструменты для классических и UML-диаграмм, а блок-схемы есть не везде. Получится неплохая программа, пересекающаяся со школьной программой и показывающая ваши знания HTML5, CSS, JavaScript и навыки проектирования пользовательского интерфейса.

Comment: Вообще интересно, нужно подумать как такое можно реализовать) А нет ли ссылки с примером?)

Comment: Это ещё не только интересно, но и нужно. Сам некоторое время назад искал программу с таким функционалом.

Comment: Народ, да вы чего?! У меня в универе у некоторых одногруппников дипломные работы проще были!

Comment: @Sasha121 будем под них равняться?

Comment: @Sasha121 Тем более, любое приложение можно реализовать с разной степенью сложности.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, визуализация [фракталов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D4%F0%E0%EA%F2%E0%EB) онлайн: стройте фракталы (на canvas) по введенным пользователем параметрам. С фракталами можно много написать, выберете, какие больше понравятся.